# How to access URL in Rails Show action in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is the URL I want to access in my show method

http://localhost:3000/students.1

### but the error is coming

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StudentsController#show
Couldn't find Student with 'id'=

def show

```
@student = Student.find(params[:id])
```

### end

my routes are

new_students GET    /students/new(.:format)  students#new

edit_students GET    /students/edit(.:format) students#edit

```
 students GET    /students(.:format)      students#show

          PATCH  /students(.:format)      students#update

          PUT    /students(.:format)      students#update

          DELETE /students(.:format)      students#destroy

          POST   /students(.:format)      students#create

     root GET    /                        students#index
```

---

Can someone tell me how do I access that students.1 in my URL so that I can display that particular student on my show page ?

Comment: The path is `/students/1` not `/students.1`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Answer (score 1):

Thats the wrong path. It should be `/students/1`.

And your routes are wrong. You can tell that the routes are off by the lack of an id segment and the fact that it maps `GET /students` to the show action instead of the index.

```
# Wrong
resource :students

# Right
resources :students
```

Pluralization is extremely important in Rails and is worth paying careful attention to. While its just one tiny letter these methods produce completely different routes.

`resource` is for [singular resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources). This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

there is some issue with your route formation

your url is not properly forming , try below

```
students_path(id: student.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `http://localhost:3000/students/1`

Check out [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) docs